# Visual Studio 2008/2010 Code Bookmarks Backup

Tags: visual-studio

How can I backup my code bookmarks? (Visual Studio 2008/2010) I would like to share them with my team...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmarks are stored in your .suo file and as such are designed to be user specific.  The suo is hidden by default for a reason :-).  It is also not plain text so cant simply be read in notepad or even notepad++.

**EDIT**

If you need to share locations in the code can you not create a custom token for the task list and use comments instead - this is a bit of a fudge and not the intended use for the task list but it would work.

Comment: A better solution to standard bookmarks...

Go to Tools/Options/Environment/Task List and add a new tag to record them.  I wanted to use the phrase 'MARK' but this word is too common, so I'm using 'BOOKMARK' set as low priority.

Whenever I want to leave a bookmark I just type "//BOOKMARK: this is a bookmark", and that's it done, simple!
To view them just open the Task List window and sort by priority or description and scroll down.

This is hugely better than standard bookmarks as they are 'pinned' with the actualy code and don't drift and can be shared with over developers.

Comment: In C++ it only shows Tasks for opened files. Also deprecated in VS 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Old question but it also applies to any other Visual Studio version. [ContextKeeper](https://ContextKeeper.io) extension will do the job. Supports Visual Studio 2022 and 2019/2017/2015/2013.

It's an extension to quickly save and restore sets of document tabs and its metadata. The "session", similar to Vim's [:mksession](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession) command, is defined as:

- **bookmarks & breakpoints**
- last opened/favorites files
- documents (tabs with code) positions, state and order
- tabs groups (including horizontal/vertical orientation)
- remembers line&column for every opened tab

It also has a powerful [git integration](https://contextkeeper.io/blog/automatic-snapshot-switching-when-changing-branches-v1/) - **automatically saves** and **restores** context when **switching between branches**.

All contexts are saved to **simple JSON files** and use **relative paths** to enable sharing them inside your team.

Comment: When you unstash your bookmarks all your folders are empty and all bookmarks lose their names

Comment: @user714171 Folders support (grouping) for breakpoints & bookmarks is not currently possible due to limitations of Visual Studio API. Similar situation is for bookmark's name - it's not supported via public VS API. I'll try to find working workaround for both if possible.